# Rails - establish_connection and nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, nested, foreign-keys

I'm having a problem creating a nested model with `establish_connection` using another database.

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :'f7-api'

  has_many :sections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :sections
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sections, allow_destroy: true
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :'f7-api'

  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :options, through: :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true
end
```

-

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on table "sections"
 violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_14e0e2a999" DETAIL: Key
 (restaurant_id)=(3) is not present in table "restaurants". : INSERT INTO
 "sections" ("title_input_id", "restaurant_id", "created_at", 
"updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
```

The form parameters from the action are (formatted):

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FLe24nnI3fITIS4bpMBDjJ0Ne+F0S3Rh9HgjYIqotR3CpbT/gHa0c3iQi‌​0yUtiCQNdNBYi0ANN75fqiZU6japw==", 
  "restaurant"=>{
    "name"=>"asd", "business_name"=>"", "cnpj"=>"", "description"=>"", 
    "url"=>"", "phone"=>"", "mobile"=>"", "website"=>"",
    "sections_attributes"=>{
      "1463797768730"=>{"title"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}
    }
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Save Restaurant"
}
```

restaurants_controller

```
  # POST /restaurants
  # POST /restaurants.json
  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.save
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def restaurant_params
      params.require(:restaurant).permit(
        :id,
        :name,
        :business_name,
        :cnpj,
        :description,
        :phone,
        :mobile,
        :website,
        :user_id,
        :street,
        :complement,
        :number,
        :lat,
        :lng,
        :zip_code,
        :neighborhood_id,
        :city_id,
        :state_id,
        :country_id,
        photos: [:id, :image, :main],
        open_hours: [:id, :weekday, :opens_at, :closes_at],
        cuisine_ids: [],
        category_ids: [],
        sections_attributes: [
          :id,
          :title,
          :restaurant_id,
          :_destroy,
          items_attributes: [
            :id,
            :title,
            {:description => []},
            :section_id,
            :price_cents,
            :not_equal,
            :_destroy,
            options_attributes: [
              :id,
              {:description => []},
              :item_id,
              :price_cents,
              :_destroy
            ]
          ]
        ]
      )
    end
```

Comment: Can you show the ActiveRecord statement that you're using to do this?

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"FLe24nnI3fITIS4bpMBDjJ0Ne+F0S3Rh9HgjYIqotR3CpbT/gHa0c3agfgRt3QNdNBYi0ANN75fqiZU6japw==",
 "restaurant"=>{"name"=>"asd",
 "business_name"=>"",
 "cnpj"=>"",
 "description"=>"",
 "url"=>"",
 "phone"=>"",
 "mobile"=>"",
 "website"=>"",
 "sections_attributes"=>{"1463797768730"=>{"title"=>"",
 "_destroy"=>"false"}}},
 "commit"=>"Save Restaurant"}

Comment: Is there a record in your restaurants table that has an id of `3`?  In rails console, what is the result of `Restaurant.find(3)`?

Comment: irb(main):001:0> Restaurant.find(3)
  Restaurant Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants" WHERE "restaurants"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Restaurant with 'id'=3

Comment: I think 3 is the id rails is trying to create the new Restaurant

Comment: If I use the sections table in the same database without the establish_connection, everything works great. What might be happening?

Comment: Can you show the controller code responsible for saving the records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove foreign_key references in postgres database

I dont know why estabilh_connection is breaking this relationship.